# fancyhdr - Re-define sectionmark

Tags: fancyhdr

This is how I've re-defined `chaptermark`:

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{\scshape{%
\chaptername\ \thechapter.%
\ #1}}{}}
```

I want to re-define `sectionmark` in the same way, using `\scshape`.

Where do I have to put `\scshape` in `\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection ~ \ #1}}`?

Comment: I'd try/use `\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\scshape\thesection ~ \ #1}}`. Note that `\scshape` doesn't take an argument, so the two braces you used after it aren't necessary. You might wanted to use `\textsc` which would take an argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting my comment into an answer:

You might use `\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\scshape\thesectio‌​n ~ \ #1}}`. Please note that `\scshape` is a switch (similar to `\bfseries`) and doesn't take an argument. You could as well use `\textsc` which would take an argument using `\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\textsc{\thesectio‌​n ~ \ #1}}}`.